# Why does my for loop not work in my void function

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

My `for` loop works outside the void function but not inside it.

I tried not using a function and it works but I need to put this `for` loop inside a function because I want to use it in other code.

It works like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        sum += i;
    }
    cout << "Sum = " << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

But not like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void somation(){
    int n, sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        sum += i;
    }
    cout << "Sum = " << sum;
}
```

This the error message I get in dev-cpp:

> ```
> D:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a- 
> crt0_c.o) In function `main':
>
> 18            C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64- 
> crt\crt\crt0_c.c      undefined reference to `WinMain'
>
> D:\CPP Projects\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Comment: On line 2: I tried using it outside a funtion ans it works, but i need to put this for loop inside a function because i want to use it in other code

Comment: Your second code list has no `main`. By what means did you think your `somation` function would be called ? `int main() { somation(); }`

Comment: A C++ program is required to have a function called `main`, which returns an `int` and takes 0 or 2 arguments. This function defines "entry point" of your program and (with some exceptions) is the first thing that will be executed.

Comment: All programs need a `main`. So renaming `main` to be `somation` is perfectly fine.  And that source file will still *compile*.  But for *linking* into a final EXE, you still need a `main` as a starting point for your program to run.

Comment: And don't get confused by `WinMain` missing: That's just because of MS not being standard conformant and having introduced its own variant. All compilers I am aware of, though, will accept the standard main function as well and make sure it gets called, so no need to care for the non-standard MS sh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program needs to have a main function (entry point for your program).

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void somation()
{

    int n, sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
    {
        sum += i;
    }
    cout << "Sum = " << sum;
}

int main()
{
    somation();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem you are having is that you are trying to execute a function without calling it in a main.
If you want to use the function somation somewhere else you can just copy it, but you always have to call the function in a main or else it won't work.

```
void somation()
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
         sum += i;
    }
    cout << "Sum = " << sum;
    return;
}

int main(){
    somation();
    return 0;
}
```